# Software Centre

Tags: software-center

I just Installed Ubuntu 12.10 via CD in offline mode and now I am unable to download anything from the software centre.

An error dialogue pops up saying

> Failed to download repositories information, check internet connection

I have tried my best following myriad number of instructions and commands,as I can see that the question has been asked several times, but till now all in vain. I even tried re installing. I tried the commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, it runs and shows

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also it shows "use this source" instead of install button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1):

You're using an outdated version on Ubuntu.  Install Ubuntu 14.04 instead, and everything will work.  Ubuntu 12.10 is not a LTS version, so questions about it really are solved by upgrading to 14.04 (the current LTS - Long Term Support - version).

The problem is that the repos have been removed from the apt-get master list server side, so what apt-get is looking for doesn't exist anymore.  Really, your best bet is to upgrade to 14.04, or 15.04 if you want a more recent (and less buggy for some GPUs) version.